# Create number grid of text objects in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

I'm trying to find a way to use animation nodes to generate a grid of numbers that would look something like this ...

[image: Desired result]

In *pseudo code*, I would imagine it working something like this:

1. Generate grid mesh
2. Get Nth mesh point
3. Generate new text object at Nth point with index value as text input

I've tried doing this in animation nodes with an object instancer. What ends up happening is that all the generated text objects end up with the same offset, and the same content (i.e. the last index value). For some reason it is only applying the values from the last iteration of the loop to all the text objects!

See here:

[image: My failed attempt]

Are there any Animation Node masters out there who can tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: try to check "Deep Copy" in the Object Instancer node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that I've answered my own question.

My mistake was using a source text object for the instancer. Instead, I just disabled the "Copy from source" setting and then selected "Text" from the drop down list of available types to instance.

[image]

The next challenge will be getting the numbers to count up horizontally instead.

***Update!***

I vastly simplified the node network from my (deleted) post yesterday, and made it able to order the numbers in anyway you want, up down left right, down up right left, etc.

[image]

There's still just the issue of not having any access to the font object material at all.

Comment: To get the numbers to count up horizontally instead of vertically, just switch the X and Y offsets in the object output

Comment: that is the better than my "quick fix" to the problem :)

Comment: My next need is to get the numbers to count in an "Up down, Up down" - i.e. getting odd numbers on one row and even numbers on the other row.

Comment: I'm going to try making two loops, one for even, one for odd.

Comment: Changed my mind, I think I can do it in math ...

Comment: @DavidGilson Please accept your answer if it answers your question.